# View, Group by Sum truncating decimals

Tags: sql-server, view

My view is as follows:

```sql
SELECT        dbo.qry_NW_Ph1_GFAnalysis_Base_PtA.OrderPeriod, dbo.HPDict_PlantGeocodes.CostCentre AS Customer, dbo.HPDict_PlantGeocodes.PlantCity, SUM(dbo.qry_NW_Ph1_GFAnalysis_Base_PtA.TruckEquivalent) 
                         AS Quantity
FROM            dbo.qry_NW_Ph1_GFAnalysis_Base_PtA INNER JOIN
                         dbo.HPDict_PlantGeocodes ON dbo.qry_NW_Ph1_GFAnalysis_Base_PtA.Plant_10 = dbo.HPDict_PlantGeocodes.PlantCode
GROUP BY dbo.qry_NW_Ph1_GFAnalysis_Base_PtA.OrderPeriod, dbo.HPDict_PlantGeocodes.CostCentre, dbo.HPDict_PlantGeocodes.PlantCity*
```

the problem is that:

- Quantity returns an integer
- But TruckEquivalent is a Decimal number

How do I get Quantity to return a decimal? Thanks!

Comment: FYI, 3 part naming for columns is [due to be deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. Alias your objects, and use those to qualify your column names.

Comment: As for if you want a decimal value, then `CAST`/`CONVERT` it. `SUM`, however, will **not** change the datatype of a column, so this means your column `TruckEquivalent` **must** be an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, table aliases are essential for readable code.  The SUM may be CAST to a DECIMAL type.

```
SELECT n.OrderPeriod, 
       h.CostCentre AS Customer, 
       h.PlantCity,
       cast(sum(n.TruckEquivalent) as decimal(16, 2)) AS Quantity
FROM  dbo.qry_NW_Ph1_GFAnalysis_Base_PtA n
      inner join dbo.HPDict_PlantGeocodes h ON n.Plant_10 = h.PlantCode
GROUP BY n.OrderPeriod,
         h.CostCentre,
         h.PlantCity;
```