# Why is SQL Server truncating my values from a decimal column?

Tags: sql-server, truncation

I'm writing a query which do some calculations over some tables to return to my application, after debugging I've found out that the undesired truncation is being done directly in SQL Server instead of my app.

I've got those two tables and columns (considering both `valued` and `pop_valued` are `decimal(38,9)`):

```
select valued 
from dbname.dbo.TABLE_SUM
where market_id_2 = 103 -- returns 2454356.000000000

select pop_valued 
from dbname.dbo.TABLE_POP
where market_id_1 = 103 -- 8035229.000000000
```

And the query that does the calculation is:

```
SELECT 
    sm.totalsortkey_bigid_0     AS totalsortkey_bigid_0,
    COALESCE(sm.market_id_2, 0) AS market_id_2,
    sm.advertiser_id_3          AS advertiser_id_3,
    sm.time_day_4               AS time_day_4,

    SUM(100.0 * (sm.valued /
          NULLIF(b.pop_valued, 0))) AS valued

FROM 
    dbname.dbo.TABLE_SUM sm
JOIN 
    dbname.dbo.TABLE_POP b ON sm.market_id_2 = b.market_id_1
                           AND sm.population_id_1 = b.population_id_0
GROUP BY 
    sm.totalsortkey_bigid_0,
    sm.market_id_2,
    sm.advertiser_id_3,
    sm.time_day_4
```

where, for market_id = 103 the 'valued' is displayed as: `30.544900`

But if I do this test query with the same values:

```
select sum(100 * (2454356.000000000 / NULLIF(8035229.000000000, 0)))
```

then I get the desired result which is: `30.544941531846821043`.

I've found some similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64369497/view-group-by-sum-truncating-decimals) and tried to apply the `cast(val as decimal(38,9))` but it didn't worked. So my question is how to avoid this truncate behavior on the query to return the desired calculation?

Comment: `select sum(100* (2454356.000000000/ NULLIF(8035229.000000000,0)) ) ` isn't a fair comparison. `select sum(100* (CONVERT(decimal(38,9),2454356.000000000)/ NULLIF(CONVERT(decimal(38,9),8035229.000000000),0)));` would be. Though I'm not sure why you're `SUM`ing a scalar value there.

Comment: I suppose the real qusetion is do your columns, `valued` and `pop_valued`, *need* a precision of **38** digits? Are you *really* like to store a value like `99999999999999999999999999999.999999999`?

Comment: Yes @GSerg, thanks. I've casted the valued and pop_valued as float and now it worked.

Comment: Blargh, a `float`? I don't think that's any better... Base-2 values and non-integer base-10 values don't reflect each other well.

Comment: Yeah, avoid floats if you're going to do arithmetic operations which require a precise result, as they are only an approximate value. check `select case when convert(float,0.1) + convert(float,0.2) + convert(float,0.3) = convert(float,0.6) then 'true' else 'false' end` if you want to be convinced.

Comment: @ThomA, I've tried with other precision data types like numeric and other decimals and all of them keep the truncating behavion... that makes no sense to me since they were meant to be more precise... only casting to float gave a result more close to the desired

Comment: Your question literally proves your comment wrong, @Fnr , and you demonstrate that a different precision works.